# Load different view based on url parameter with out changing controller action method in asp mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-routing

I was wondering if below hack is possible or not.
Tried multiple ways but it will require some conditional statements in action method.

I am looking for solution based on routing most probably but not sure how it is possible.

Suppose I have single Acton Method Index()

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

above method is under home controller.
In addition inside Views > Home folder there are two view files...

1. Index.cshtml
2. Index_New.cshtml.

I believe that it is possible to load different Views using id passed in URL parameter but that will require change in above action method and i don't want that.

Can we do something without changing action method so that

- http://example.com/Home/Index should load Index.cshtml

and

- http://example.com/Home/New/Index should load Index_New.cshtml?

Comment: possible but you will have to create a new action and in in routing map the new url to that action

Comment: Not without changing the action method, no. You could branch *within the same view* based on the URL to display different HTML, without requiring changes to the action, but you couldn't load entirely different views.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new action method. Update your route registrations so that the request `yourSite/Home/News/Index` will be handled by this new aciton method.

The below code uses attribute routing to specify the route pattern for the new action method. You can pass the view name to the view method if you want to return something different than the convention (the action name)

```
[Route("Home/News/Index")]
public ActionResult NewsIndex()
{
    return View("Index_New");
}
```